Spring Batch error when call from a Spring Schedule
I'm completing a Spring Boot upgrade from 2.7.2 to 3.2.6, with a Spring Batch upgrade to 5.1.2 according to this.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide
The job is pretty simple and works when called from a RestController
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job myJob;

JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate(...).toJobParameters();
jobLauncher.run(myJob, params);

And the job looks as such:
@Bean
Job myJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step1, Step step2) throws Exception 
{

   SimpleJobBuilder builder =
         new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .preventRestart()
                .start(step1)
                .next(step2);

The job runs fine from a Controller, but not from a scheduler.
@Autowired
Job myJob;

@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Scheduled(cron = "...")
public void performQuebecP11() throws Exception {
    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("...", new 
    Date()).toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(p11BatchJobQuebec, params);

I get the following error:
2024-07-04 12:31:04.533 [scheduling-1] ERROR  org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute:259  - Encountered an error executing step step1 in job myJob
jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:517) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:2532) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1398) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1393) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar:6.4.8.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy165.flush(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:106) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:170) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:227) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:388) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:255) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:369) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:240) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:229) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:317) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at ca.mycorp.trs.batch.scheduler.BatchJobScheduler.perform(BatchJobScheduler.java:41) ~[main/:?]

So I tried the following:
@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron = "...")
public void perform()

And I got:
2024-07-04 11:52:01.024 [scheduling-1] ERROR  org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError:95  - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.lambda$getObject$0(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:201) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy163.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
        at ca.mycorp.trs.batch.scheduler.BatchJobScheduler.performQuebecP11(BatchJobScheduler.java:42) ~[main/:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at ca.mycorp.trs.batch.scheduler.BatchJobScheduler$$SpringCGLIB$$0.performQuebecP11(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.6.jar:1.12.6]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]

The step1 is the following:
@Autowired
JpaItemWriter<MyEntity> updateDBWriter;


@Bean
Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
    return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository).<MyEntity, MyOutput>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
            .reader(makeFetcher())
            .processor(makeProcessor())
            .writer(updateDBWriter)
            .build();
}

I have been stripping the project down for days to try to resolve this. Anyone could tell me how to improve the transaction management such this job works from both the RestController and the Spring Schedule?
